# Probability of correct identification from m cryptograms and k RSA public keys

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability

Here is a statistical model of [the crypto/privacy problem I'm trying to solve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/90009/555): computing probability of identifying which of $k$ RSA public keys of same bit size was used to prepare $m$ cryptograms, under some standard hypothesis.

In an experiment parameterized by integers $k>0$ and $m>0$,

- It is drawn $k$ reals $n_i$ as the product of two reals each independent and uniform in $[\sqrt{1/2},1]$, so that $n_i\in[1/2,1]$ with some vaguely triangular distribution.
- It is drawn $m$ reals $c_\ell$ independent and uniform in $[0,n_0]$, computed their maximum $w=\max c_\ell$, and their mean $x=\frac1m\sum c_\ell$, thus with $E(x)=n_0/2$.
- The experiment outputs $1$ if for each of $k-1$ integers $i$ with $0<i<k$, if holds $n_i<w$ *or* $\left\lvert x-n_0/2\right\rvert<\left\lvert x-n_i/2\right\rvert$; it outputs $0$ otherwise.

In other words, the outcome is $1$ when $x$ is closer to $E(x)$ than it would be if the $c_\ell$ had been generated as uniformly drawn in $[0,n_i]$ for some $i>0$ *and* this $i$ could not be conclusively ruled out by the test $n_i<w$. I think this matches the probability of the best strategy (I welcome comment on that).

I would like to make a graph with curves for the expectancy of the experiment at a few discrete values of $k$ (say the 16 powers of two from $2$ to $2^{16}$), versus values of $m$ (on a log scale) from $1$ up to what it takes for expectancy like 95%. That means many billions for $m$, which begs for a little math rather than massive Monte-Carlo simulation, at least for the $c_\ell$.

I see that $\Pr[n_i<w]$ is $0$ when $n_i>n_0$, or $1-(n_i/n_0)^m$ otherwise, and how to evaluate the later accurately. I see that $x$ has [Bates distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_distribution), with $E(x)=n_0/2$ and $\sigma(x)=n_0/\sqrt{12m}$. But I'm unsure about what to do after that, even if I resort to simulation for the $k$ values of $n_i$. I have trouble with the *or* condition between dependent events, and even with evaluating $\Pr\bigl[\,\left\lvert x-n_0/2\right\rvert<\left\lvert x-n_i/2\right\rvert\,\bigr]$.